# ARM Assembly- Link Register doesn't return main subroutine

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, keil

I would like to get decimal input from user from Termite and store the input in R7 register. My code works fine I tested and observed correct output at R7. But when I run, after my q4convert is done I want it to return main as it should be. However, when the line

`take       BL      InChar`

is executed, link register stores this line and keeps returning this line after q4convert.s reaches end with the following statement.

```
            POP     {R1,R4,R5,R6}
            BX      LR
```

My main

```
;LABEL      DIRECTIVE       VALUE       COMMENT         
            AREA        sdata, DATA, READONLY
            THUMB
EnterMSG    DCB         0x0A
            DCB         "Enter the number of food parcels. Expected Input format ends with '*' i.e. = 520*,100*,15*"
            DCB         0x0D
            DCB         0x04
            
            AREA    main,   READONLY,   CODE
            THUMB
            EXTERN  OutStr
            EXTERN  q4convert
            EXPORT __main           

__main      PROC
            LDR     R5,=EnterMSG        
            BL      OutStr          
            BL      q4convert
done        B       done            
            ENDP
```

My subroutine that takes input digit by digit and stores it in R7.

```
            AREA    convert, READONLY, CODE
            THUMB
            EXPORT  q4convert           ; make available to other programs
            EXTERN  InChar
                
q4convert   PROC
            PUSH    {R1,R4,R5,R6}
take        BL      InChar              ;Get n
            CMP     R5,#0x2A            ;Example input format ends with * whose asci code is 0x2A
            STRBNE  R5,[R6],#-1         ;Store digits as descending order. Dont store ASCII OF '*'
            ADDNE   R4,#1               ;R4 Counts the digits. No addition for '*'
            BNE     take
            SUB     R4,#1               ;Sets R4 to Digit-1. This will be used to reach the correct address with offset. 
            MOV32   R6,#0x20000500
            MOV     R10,#10
point           
            LDRB    R1,[R6],#-1         ;Point the correct digit starting from most significant.
            SUB     R1,#48              ;R1 has the digit.  
            PUSH    {R4}            
loop        
            MUL     R1,R10
            SUBS    R4,#1
            BNE     loop            
            POP     {R4}
            SUBS    R4,#1
            ADD     R7,R1               ;R7 is the our input number.    
            CMP     R4,#0
            BNE     point
            BEQ     final
final       
            LDRB    R1,[R6]
            SUB     R1,#48
            ADD     R7,R1               ;Adds least significant digit.
            POP     {R1,R4,R5,R6}
            BX      LR
            ENDP
```

My InChar.s, OutStr.s files are prewritten files by TexasInstrument there is nothing wrong with them.
OutStr prints a string located in memory. Starting address of string is passed to R5.
InChar stores characters in R5.

My board is Texas Instruments EK-TM4C123GXL

I'll be glad if someone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: There is only one link register.  You need to save this register in `q4convert` before calling any more functions.  The easiest solution is to change `push {r1, r4, r5, r6}` to `push {r1, r4, r5, r5, lr}` and `pop {r1, r4, r5, r6}` to `pop {r1, r4, r5, r6, pc}`.

Comment: I understood why we push lr but you popped pc instead of LR . Why is that?

Comment: PC is the program counter, by popping the old LR into PC, we return from the function.  With ARMv6-M (which this looks like it is; you didn't say), you cannot pop `LR`, only `PC`.  Since you want to return anyway, this is a good solution.

Comment: I am using Texas Instruments EK-TM4C123GXL with arm cortex m4. I tried to pop LR and it worked. Can i pop PC for m4 processors as well?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to pop LR on an ARM-Cortex M4 (which uses ARMv7-M).  However, is there really a need to?  `pop {r1, r4, r5, r6, pc}` does the same thing as `pop {r1, r4, r5, r6, lr}; bx lr` but in one instruction.

Comment: Yeah you are right. With pop pc I don't need to branch to LR anymore since I already set my pc to lr with that pop. Thank you so much.

Comment: ADDNE   R4,#1  this does not resemble an armv6-m.  so an armv7-m as indicated.

Comment: popping lr then bx lr goes back to the full sized arm and for armv4t you have to do it that way if you want to support thumb interworking, armv5t and later you can pop pc and it will switch modes.  armv7-m you can pop either lr or pc but not both.  If pushing lr for nesting then it saves an instruction to pop pc

Comment: Before doing any assembly language work you need the processor documentation.  This is all shown in the architectural reference manual for the armv7-m (can I pop lr, what bl does to lr, etc).

Comment: Take care too, the ARM ABI requires 8-byte stack alignment across function calls in different translation units.  The easiest way to ensure this is to push and pop even numbers of registers.